# Determining radius of convergence

Tags: complex-analysis

Determine the radius of convergence of the power series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(4-3i)^n}$$

I tried using the ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Bigg|\frac{\frac{z^{2(n+1)}}{(4-3i)^{n+1}}}{\frac{z^{2n}}{(4-3i)^n}}\Bigg|$$

$$= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Bigg|\frac{z^{2(n+1)}}{z^{2n}}\Bigg| * \Bigg|\frac{(4-3i)^n}{(4-3i)^{n+1}}\Bigg|$$

$$= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|z|^2}{5}$$

How do I determine the radius of convergence from here? I have no $n$ left in my limit, so either I did something wrong or I used the wrong method.

Comment: You've computed the limit; when is it less than $1$?

Comment: Oh, so thats how I am supposed to look at it. That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have obtained the limit of $|\frac {a_{n+1}} {a_n}|$ as $\frac  {|z|^{2}} 5$. So the series is convergent if $\frac  {|z|^{2}} 5 <1$ and divergent if $\frac  {|z|^{2}} 5 >1$. The radius of convergence is $\sqrt 5$.

Comment: That makes sense, didn't think about it that way. Thanks!